# React cannot preserv list between route changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this little projekt where I enter some user info into a form and on submit it will display it on the same page in a table. This seem to work as intended but then when I click on Home page and then back to the form page the list is empty. I would like the list to persist as long as you browse the site.

I've been struggling with this for a while and would love to get some help.
I'll post the components.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import PersonList from "./Components/PersonList";
import PersonDetails from "./Components/PersonDetails";
import LoginForm from "./Components/LoginForm";
import { UserContext } from "./Components/UserContext";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{value, setValue }}>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/PersonList" element={<PersonList />} />
            <Route path="/Components/PersonDetails/:id/*" element={<PersonDetails />} />
            <Route path="/LoginForm" element={<LoginForm />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import { useContext, useState } from "react";

export default function Navbar() {
    const {value, setValue} = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
  <nav className="navbar">
    <h1>React Assignment</h1>

    <div className="links">
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/PersonList">Person List</Link>
      { !value && <Link to="/LoginForm">Login</Link> }
      { value && <Link to={"/"} onClick={() => {setValue(null);}} >Logout</Link> }
      {value}
    </div>
  </nav>
  )
}
```

```
import { useState } from "react";
import UserForm from "./UserForm";
import UserList from "./UserList";


const PersonList = () => {
      // create array using useState to store the contact form data.
  const [contacts, updateContacts] = useState([]);

  // update contact state.
   const addContact = (contact) => {
     updateContacts([...contacts, contact]);

  };

    return (
        <div className="personlist">
            <UserForm addContact={addContact} />
            <UserList contacts={contacts} />
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default PersonList;
```

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

// retrieve addContact function from PersonList.js as props.
export default function UserForm({ addContact }) {

  // useState hook to manage state in functional components.
  const [contactInfo, setContactInfo] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    age: "",
    nationality: "",
    email: "",
  });

  // update input fields.
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setContactInfo({ ...contactInfo, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  // submit data to addContact function.
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addContact(contactInfo);
    // clear input fields after submit
    setContactInfo({
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      age: "",
      nationality: "",
      email: "",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-container w-50">
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Contact Form</h3>

        <Form.Control
          size="sm"
          type="text"
          name="firstname"
          placeholder="First Name"
          required
          value={contactInfo.firstname}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <Form.Control
          size="sm"
          type="text"
          name="lastname"
          required
          placeholder="Last Name"
          value={contactInfo.lastname}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <Form.Control
          size="sm"
          type="number"
          name="age"
          placeholder="Age"
          value={contactInfo.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <Form.Control
          size="sm"
          type="text"
          name="nationality"
          placeholder="Nationality"
          value={contactInfo.nationality}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <Form.Control
          size="sm"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          required
          value={contactInfo.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <p></p>
        <Button variant="primary" size="sm" type="submit">
          Submit Contact
        </Button>
        <p></p>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// retrieve contacts from PersonList.js as props
export default function UserList({ contacts }) {

  if (contacts.length === 0) {
    return <h5>The list is empty</h5>;
  } else {

    return (
      <Table className="w-100" bordered hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="tablelinks">
          {/* use .map to loop */}
          {contacts.map((contact) => (

            <tr key={uuid()}>
              <td>
              <Link to={`/Components/PersonDetails/${contact.firstname+contact.lastname}`}>
                {contact.firstname}
              </Link>
              </td>
              <td>{contact.lastname}</td>
              <td>{contact.age}</td>
              <td>{contact.nationality}</td>
              <td>{contact.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just needing to persist the `contacts` state so it is available when navigating to the `"/PersonList"` path then the obvious solution is to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor component that remains mounted while routed components are mounted/unmounted. The `App` component is this ancestor.

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  // create array using useState to store the contact form data.
  const [contacts, updateContacts] = useState([]);

  // update contact state.
   const addContact = (contact) => {
     updateContacts(contacts => [...contacts, contact]);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{value, setValue }}>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/PersonList" element={<PersonList {...{ addContact, contacts }} />} />
            <Route path="/Components/PersonDetails/:id/*" element={<PersonDetails />} />
            <Route path="/LoginForm" element={<LoginForm />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
const PersonList = ({ contacts, addContact }) => {
  return (
    <div className="personlist">
      <UserForm addContact={addContact} />
      <UserList contacts={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additionally if you need to also persist the `contacts` state when the page is reloaded/refreshed then you'll need to persist the state to something more long-term. Initialize/persist the state from/to localStorage.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  // create array using useState to store the contact form data.
  const [contacts, updateContacts] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contacts")) ?? []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Drew for a good explanation and for the code! This helped.